# Stay focused on element if click and hold starts inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I am using the qtip jquery plugin, and ran into a strange problem. I have a large "tooltip" that scrolls. fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yu9tb1wn/

In firefox if I click and try to select text, the div will scroll when I leave through the top or bottom. This is expected and desired because that's how most windows behave.

However in IE and Chrome the tooltip disappears, because it is supposed to disappear on mouseleave.

How can I get IE and Chrome to behave like Firefox? Maybe there are some events I need to use that I'm unaware of.

If you try that fiddle in the different browsers, try to select all the text and you should see the behavior I'm talking about.

simple qtip code:

```
 $('a[title]').qtip({
    hide: {
    delay:250,
      fixed: true,
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to make this work on Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/d6b5wmLk/12/

```
var b = true;
  $('a[title]').qtip({
    hide: {
        delay:250,
      fixed: true,
    },
    events: {
        hide: function(event, api) {
            if(!b) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
  });
    $( "html" ).mousedown(function() {
    b = false;
    });
  $( "html" ).mouseup(function() {
    b = true;
    $('a[title]').qtip('hide');
    });
```

Comment: You rock Tim. I had to make a small change so that it wouldn't hide the tooltip if I moused up inside of it. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6b5wmLk/14/. And IE is a different story because it won't even scroll, but close enough :)

Comment: Good catch. (I stay as far as i can from IE)

Answer (score 0):

i was looking and the library and i believe that you can increment the delay a little more to achieve that. But besides that i don't see any other way without modifying the library

Comment: That won't really work, it just delays how long it stays open after mouseleave. Its not really specific to the library. I'm looking for a way to mimic Firefox's behavior of  staying focused on the element if you mousedown and leave.